# DataFix or CodeFix for existing records in MongoDB NoSQL database

Tags: mongodb, database

We have a NodeJS/Java application deployed in Live Env for the last 4 months. It uses MongoDB as the backend.

The Application creates new customer records with 20 fields and so far it has created 1000 customers in the MongoDB database in Live Env.
We have a new requirement now which requires a new field called "Rating" to be added to the Customer Collection.

The new version of the Application is expected to create new customer records with this new field now with different values.

1. Would it be better to go for a "datafix" script to modify the existing 1000 records to have the new "Rating" field populated with the default value 5 in Production env during the deployment of the new version of the application?

or

2. Would it be better to go for a "codefix" approach, where no changes are performed to the existing customer records in the MongoDB database. If there is no field called "Rating" for an existing Customer record, the Application will always consider it as having a "Rating" field with a default value of 5. MongoDB is a schemaless NoSQL database, so I think this approach can be used.

Coming from a relational database background, I like the first approach. I would like to keep the database clean and consistent with the number of fields the same and correctly populated for all records in a collection in the MongoDB database.

I am fairly new to MongoDB database.

I was wondering what other MongoDB experienced users think about these 2 approaches..

Comment: Both would work.  Which one is better depends on a lot of factors like your use case, business needs, difficulty of updating the application, tolerance of the database being slow or offline, etc.  Basically YMMV, test before you implement.

Comment: thanks Joe, I think we should list the pros and cons of both the approaches with the list of factors that you have mentioned and look at them for our application. Choosing a "codefix" approach just because MongoDB is schema less does not sound like a good idea.